# Center align horizontal navigation bar CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation

I've tried changing the display type to inline-block, changing text align to center, and changing the position to relative, but nothing I've tried seems to work.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="header">
  <h1>Politics and Social Media</h1>
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="index.html" class="button selected">Overview</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="media.html" class="button">Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="author.html" class="button">Author</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <img src="images/barack.jpg" width="100%" height="75%" margin="0" 
    padding="0" alt="Barack Obama and Joe Biden looking at phone" >
</div><!--end of header-->
```

CSS Code:

```
#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0; 
}   

ul#menu {
    list-style: none; 
    margin-left: 0;
} 
ul#menu li {
    float: left; 
    margin-left: -40px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve?

CSS:

```
#header {
    text-align: center;
}
#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0; 
}   

ul#menu {
    list-style: none; 
    padding-left: 0px;
} 
    ul#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<h1>Politics and Social Media</h1>
<div id="navbar">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="button selected">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="media.html" class="button">Media</a></li>
        <li><a href="author.html" class="button">Author</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<img src="images/barack.jpg" width="100" height="75" margin="0" 
padding="0" alt="Barack Obama and Joe Biden looking at phone" >
</div><!--end of header-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul#menu {
  list-style: none; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your css so you have parent > text-align:center and child > display:inline-block;

```
ul#menu {
    list-style: none; 
    margin-left: 0;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px;
} 
ul#menu li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yee9zL5p/)